# Удаление блоков через некоторое время

Tags: css3, css-animation, html, анимация, css

Добавляю новые блоки через js на страничку, после этого сразу происходит анимация css3 с этим блоком.

Как удалить или убрать блок через несколько секунд?

Аннимация не может изменить например с display:block на display:none или height:auto на height:0px. Изменение его позиции или height: 0% не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как добавляете новые блоки при помощи JS, то может стоит и убирать их скриптом (*если честно, и анимировал бы наверно, тоже, для поддержки ie*)?

Используете jQuery? Если да то можно после добавления болка таймаут:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#id').hide(); }, 5000);
```

Если jQuery не используете, стоит написать так:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('id').style.display='block';
}, 5000);
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/Wrfb4/

Хотя я тут подумал, если использовать CSS то может помочь свойство:

```
visibility: visible; visibility: hidden;
```